# Find area of solid using cylindrical shell method

Tags: calculus, area

Here's my problem, I have to use the shell method to find the area bounded between f(x)=4x-x^2 and y=3 by rotating about y=2. I understand I have to first solve for x. Which is weird because I have two x variables with different powers. So does this mean I am going to have x on both sides? How would I use the shell method if this is the case?

Comment: You aren't allowed to use washer method?

Comment: If you aren't I think is going to be a lot more uglier. We have $-x^2+4x=y$. Factoring a -1 out on the left hand side: $-(x^2-4x)=y$. Completing the square. $-(x^2-4x+4)=y-4$. Now this gives us $-(x-2)^2=y-4$ This should make it easier for you to put x in terms of y now. You will have two equations and you will have to use both one for the left side of the vertex of your parabola and the other for the right hand side of your vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]You only need one of those equations since both regions we want to rotate are equal regions if that makes sense. So you should solve that equation above and get $x =\pm \sqrt{4-y}+2$. Well use the right hand side of the parabola in rotate it. We will also use the axis of symmetry of our parabola to help guide us to what we need to put in our formula. $2 \cdot \int_3^4 2 \pi (\sqrt{4-y}+2-2) \cdot (y-2) dy$. The factor of 2 in front of the integral there comes from that we need to rotate both sides of $x=2$ about $y=2$. This answer should be equivalent to what we get doing the washer method $\pi \int_1^3 ((4x-x^2-2)^2-(3-2)^2) dx$

Comment: @Tyler August I also put a picture showing I only rotated one side (the region that contains the pink ) and multiplied that result by 2 to get the volume as if I rotated both sides about y=2.

Comment: thank you very much! My teacher said to split the integral a to b (f(y)dy) ==> to become integral a to c (f(y)dy) + integral c to b (f(y)dy) is that person correct as well?

Comment: I don't know about that. I do not see how to visualize that.

Comment: Last question i promise =D  why is it (sqrt(4-y)+2-2) instead of  (sqrt(4-y)+2-3)?

Comment: x=2 is the axis of symmetry. x=2 is the vertical line that divides the parabola in perfect halves. (2,y(2)) is the vertex of the parabola. That is how I got the shell height there to be x(y)-2.

Comment: I tried to show this in my picture above.

Comment: The region I put in pink is bounded by $x=\sqrt(4-y)+2$ from the right and $x=2$ from the left